# Using derived class in base class

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance

is it possible, specifically in Objective-C, to use inherited class in base class, example:

```
Class BaseClass
{
  InheritedClass memberVariable;
}

Class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
  // implementation goes here
}
```

EDIT: More detailed explanation:

Imagine real world situation, where you have

```
Album:
- Title
- Artist

Song:
- Title
- Artist
- Duration
```

So you can say that Album class can be base class for Song class as follows:

```
Class Album
{
  Title;
  Artist;
}

Class Song : Album
{
  Duration;
}
```

Now, if you need to store album's songs in the Album class, you will end up with something like this:

```
Class Album
{
  Title;
  Artist;
  Songs[];
}
```

Or am I generally wrong, or missing some basics?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I my situation, I have 4 very similar objects A, B, C, D, and basically, B extends A, C extends B, and D extends A. On the other hand though, B and D needs to have C as member variable... I'm trying to figure solution with as less repeated member variables as possible and reuse as much code as possible.

Comment: That didn't really clear anything up. *Why* do B and D need C as a member variable?

Comment: Its because of already existing API.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen, I've added some detailed explanation, hope it helps bit more.

Comment: That helps a lot, and I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable for a class to have an instance variable (the ObjC term for what you're calling a member variable), or property, whose type is a subclass of itself.

Here's a simple, compilable program that demonstrates something like what you're asking in Objective-C:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Song;

@interface Album : NSObject
    @property (strong) NSString *artist;
    @property (strong) NSString *title;
    @property (strong) NSArray *songs; 
    @property (strong) Song *bestSong;
@end

@interface Song : Album
    @property (weak) Album *album;
    @property NSTimeInterval duration;
@end

@implementation Album
@end

@implementation Song
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Album *album = [[Album alloc] init];
        Song *song1 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *song2 = [[Song alloc] init];
        album.songs = @[song1, song2];
        album.bestSong = song1;
        song1.album = album;
        song2.album = album;

        NSLog(@"Album: %@", album);
        NSLog(@"songs: %@", album.songs);
        NSLog(@"bestSong: %@", album.bestSong);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Album: <Album: 0x7fcc3a40a3e0>
songs: (
    "<Song: 0x7fcc3a40a5e0>",
    "<Song: 0x7fcc3a40a670>"
)
bestSong: <Song: 0x7fcc3a40a5e0> bestSong: <Song: 0x7ff48840a580>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possibile, but you may not store an object like is possible in C++, you need to store a pointer to it:

```
Class BaseClass
{
    InheritedClass* memberVariable;
}
```

Then the pointer may point to a InheritedClass object.